# Variable parameters in C# Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, parameters

Is it possible to have a C# lambda/delegate that can take a variable number of parameters that can be invoked with a Dynamic-invoke?

All my attempts to use the 'params' keyword in this context have failed.

---

**UPDATE WITH WORKING CODE FROM [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3581142/783175):**

```
delegate void Foo(params string[] strings);

static void Main(string[] args)                       
{
    Foo x = strings =>
    {
        foreach(string s in strings)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    };

    //Added to make it clear how this eventually is used :)
    Delegate d = x;

    d.DynamicInvoke(new[]{new string[]{"1", "2", "3"}});
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far to give a better idea of what you're looking for?

Comment: I think he's trying to do `Func<params TIn[] list, TOut> func`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work when passing the arguments directly to `DynamicInvoke()` is because `DynamicInvoke()` expects an array of objects, one element for each parameter of the target method, and the compiler will interpret a single array as the *params* array to `DynamicInvoke()` instead of a single argument to the target method (unless you cast it as a single `object`).

You can also call `DynamicInvoke()` by passing an array that contains the target method's parameters array. The outer array will be accepted as the argument for `DynamicInvoke()`'s single *params* parameter and the inner array will be accepted as the *params* array for the target method.

```
delegate void ParamsDelegate(params object[] args);

static void Main()
{  
   ParamsDelegate paramsDelegate = x => Console.WriteLine(x.Length);

   paramsDelegate(1,2,3); //output: "3"
   paramsDelegate();      //output: "0"

   paramsDelegate.DynamicInvoke((object) new object[]{1,2,3}); //output: "3"
   paramsDelegate.DynamicInvoke((object) new object[]{}); //output: "0"

   paramsDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new []{new object[]{1,2,3}}); //output: "3"
   paramsDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new []{new object[]{}});      //output: "0"
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something. What would be the point of calling `DynamicInvoke` on a `ParamsDelegate`? Or do you think it's just in case you have a `ParamsDelegate` typed as `Delegate`?

Comment: +1 for approach without `DynamicInvoke`. `DynamicInvoke` is something I would try my best to avoid even without benchmarking. It's just a little too slow.

Comment: In 2015, `paramsDelegate(new object[] { 1, 2, 3} );` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, but any of the parameters it does take can be an array.

Without more details, that's the long and short of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, but with a little help, you can almost fake it:

```
object[] Params(params object[] args) { return args;}

// :

Action<string, object[]> CWL = 
                  (format,  args) => Console.WriteLine(format, args);

CWL("{0}, {1}", Params(1,2));
```

Comment: Man, once Microsoft introduced those `Action`* and `Func`* delegates it's like everybody forgot that you're actually allowed to declare your own as well...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mark's answer, I'd create an extension method to clean up a bit:

```
static DynamicInvokeParams(this ParamsDelegate delegate, params object[] args)
{
  delegate.DynamicInvoke(new [] {args});
}
```

And then you just have to say:

```
paramsDelegate.DyanamicInvokeParams(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: But why would you do this when you could just write `paramsDelegate(1, 2, 3);`?

Comment: Fair point; I guess the OP probably wants to use DynamicInvoke because they have an array, so it's more likely to be `paramsDelegate.DynamicInvokeParams(new []{1, 2, 3})` which is still a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's a very crucial point that isn't being discussed here, and that's that **if you've defined a delegate type that takes a `params` argument, there's very little point to calling `DynamicInvoke` on it at all**. The *only* scenario I can imagine in which this would come into play is if you have a delegate of your custom type and you are passing it as a parameter to some method that accepts a `Delegate` argument and calls `DynamicInvoke` on *that*.

But let's look at this code in the OP's update:

```
delegate void Foo(params string[] strings);

static void Main(string[] args)                       
{
    Foo x = strings =>
    {
        foreach(string s in strings)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    };

    x.DynamicInvoke(new[]{new string[]{"1", "2", "3"}});
}
```

The `DynamicInvoke` call above is totally superfluous. It would be much more sensible for that last line to read:

```
x("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Yes in this simplified case it would be useless but in the actual implementation case its not as it gets turned into a general delegate that is called elsewhere.  I will update my post to make this more obvious.

Comment: @wb: OK, in that case then I can understand your need to work this out. I'm going to update my answer with an explanation that I think will help you.

Comment: I am still a little unsure why the ..new[]{... part is needed though I should add.

Comment: I have the same question as above!    Why is there double boxing needed on this for DynamicInvoke()?

foo.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { new[] { arg1, arg2 } });

Argument expected is object[] and putting all the arguments into a string[] to match the delegate makes sense.   But type conversion?